# Android studio - no launch to last version of app and no project structure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

In android studio, I had a project that was working in first place but then I created multiple copy of it in other paths to add changes to these copies instead of the original.

Afterwards, I noticed that the emulator shows up but doesn't launch the app I am trying to run. I followed a tutorial on YouTube that opens the setting app on the emulator and clears launcher data. then nothing changed.. I noticed that no matter how many changes I am adding to the file, nothing changes in the old app icon existing on the emulator.

Things got much worse later when I noticed that there is no modules or any other folders in the project structure except the SDK and when the older project versions were found to have same problem suddenly.

Even when I create a new project that is empty, same thing happens and the app crashes once it's installed.

Android app icon button before run appears in the project with a red cross over it.

Both the emulator and the mobile device don't get the latest version of the app I am trying to install.

I tried to make project, build, run, clean project, sync with gradle file, invalidate cache & restart. However, none of these solutions seem to work.

No idea what is going on.. things seem to be messed up and all online sources seem to be less useless to me.

Note: I am using Android studio V 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

so, I found that the best solution to this problem is to uninstall the current version of Android studio and SDK folder and reinstall it from scratch.. hope that helps